# Anyone run recurring payments in their website? Preferably; Paypal API

Tags: api, paypal, recurring-billing

I'm wrapping up my startup and will need to implement Paypal API into my sign up page.

**Does anyone use recurring payments via Paypal API integrated into their billing? Better yet, guide me to a trustable developer with experience or will I have to use Elance?**

I need it to go to a welcome/get started screen in their logged in account once they hit the 'create account' button after filling out billing info. I was also wondering, can you leave the CSC (3 digit security code) field out with integration, because it makes things very hard for recurring payments. I'd like to stick with Paypal, as I have been very satisfied with them for a few years now; I already checked out Chargify, authorize.net, etc.

I'd love to see someone with something like this set up already to take a look at and ask a few questions.

Answer (score 1):

On the paypal website are some code samples for developers. I don't know if there are any for recurring payments but one-time payments code snippets you will find. Very easy to set up. 
I have a donate-button and it works fine without much trouble.